# Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: c#, console-application, rdlc

I have a Console application that generate rdlc report to pdf. I successfully generate the pdf file but when I add a dataset to my rdlc file, I have this error.

Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'.
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.'

Here's my code:

```
            const int extension = 1;
            
            var path = "Report1.rdlc";

            //var path = $"{_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}" + "\\Reports\\test.rdl";

            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "rp1", "Test Value to parameter" } };

            var localReport = new LocalReport(path);

            var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, extension, parameters);

            byte[] file = result.MainStream;

            using (Stream stream = new FileStream("output.pdf", FileMode.Create))
            {
                stream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
            }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and post an [mcve], including any extensions you've added to LocalReport. And post the contents of your RDL file.

Comment: Which part in the code adds dataset to rdlc file? Which line in the code throws the error?

Comment: This part throw an error.

```var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, extension, parameters);```

Comment: I am using ```AspNetCore.Reporting```

Comment: The error is related to the data source for `DataSet1`, but your sample code does not include the parts that provide the data source.